# How Do I Create this Page Swipe Behaviour in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I want to implement this page swipe behaviour in Flutter as shown in the picture. The user should be able to drag the screen from the right edge of the screen to the left up until the page is dragged halfway through the screen. Once released, the app will move onto a new page.

Desired Outcome

[image]

Comment: I think this is using PageView. give a try with it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Slidable Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) and wrap the whole page in a slideable.

```
Slidable(
    key:UniqueyKey(),
    endActionPane: ActionPane(
        onDismissed: (){}, // Leave empty, confirmDismiss will handle event
        confirmDismiss: () asnyc {
            // function that rerender page with next question
        } 
        children: [] //list of widgets to show when slide
     child: // this is the widget that shows and will be slideable
```

if you want to have both sides you just add startActionPane aswell.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for! I've tried implementing it but there are a small details I'm not sure how to configure and can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Do you know if I can set it so that only the right edge of the screen is swipeable? Can I also make it where it updates the page to the next question when the slideable is fully extended?

Comment: @ThatKid i just edited my answer with an example, hope it will help